# Retrieve JSON data for authentication

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, authentication

I am trying to make a login authentication using php to match the username and password and echo it as a JSON object.

The form is to be sent using ajax and also read the returned JSON data. This is the part I am having trouble with.

My html looks like this:

```
<form id='logform' method='post' >
   <label for="username">User Name:&nbsp;</label><input id='user_name' type='text' name='username' required placeholder='User Name' />
   <label for="password">Password:&nbsp;</label><input type='password' placeholder="Password" name='password' id="password" required />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" value="Log In"  />
   <input type="button" id="cancel_hide" value="Cancel" />
 </form>
```

sendLogDetails.php:

```
<?php
 include("dbconnect.php");
 $numrows=0;
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $username=$_POST['username'];

 $query="select username, fname, lname, memcat from members where (username='$username' && password='$password')";
$link = mysql_query($query);
if (!$link) {
 echo 3;
  die();
 }

 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($link);
 if ($numrows>0){  // authentication is successfull
 $rows = array();
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($link)) {
 $rows[] = $r;
}
$json=json_encode($rows);  
echo $json;
} else {
echo 3;  // authentication was unsuccessfull
}
?>
```

And the jQuery is as follows:

```
$("#login").click(function(){

    username=$("#username").val();
    password=$("#password").val();

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/sendLogDetails.php",
        data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
        success: function(html){
          if(html=='true')
          {
            sessionStorage.setItem("user", $("#username").val());
          }

          else
          {
                $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password");
          }

        },

    });
     return false;
});
```

The above code sends through the username and password and when I check the response in my console log it shows the data from the queried table. I am wondering how I can then retrieve this data to set it in session storage???

Comment: don't mix data types for return data... use json for both server side cases

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success function should look like this `success: function(data) {...`

Then data is the JSON object **but as a string**.  You then use `var object=JSON.parse(data)` to retrieve the actual object.

You can then do whatever you want with is by addressing the new `object` variable

**EDIT**

```
success: function(data) {
    try {
        object = $.parseJSON(data);
    } catch (e) {
        // here you didn't get JSON back so we can assume it was an error, run your error code in here.  data will still be the error number (3)
        return false;
    }
    //run your code on the json object here.
}
```

**LOOPING THROUGH AN OBJECT**

```
for (var key in object) {
    //this if just checks if the key has a value, it is required
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value=object[key];
        //then we need to put the key and the value into session storage
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to do this please? I change the success function but am unsure how to access the json data or set my if statement:

    `success: function(data){
    var object=JSON.parse(data)
          if(data=='???'){`

Comment: As far as I can tell you `data` will either be returned as a JSON string, or just the single integer `3`, in which case we can do this.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to this, I tried the method you suggested and when I `alert(data)` I get the result "object object". I'm looking to retrieve the data in the json object and also use an if statement to enact functions if the json is returned from the server. Am I being clear enough?

Comment: lol, ok, the "object object" thing you get is because browsers don't convert objects to strings when they are alerted.  Use `console.log(data)` and you will see the object that you have saved.  Press F12 to view the console in your browser.

Comment: Thanks that's working! Now how do I set items from the data to session storage?

Comment: Edited the question to show you how to loop through an object, and then put each key value pair into session storage

Comment: I've noticed that since I've implemented the above that it will run  even if the password is incorrect.

Comment: This conversation is getting really long and you don't have enough reputation to chat.  Could you possibly chat here http://us19.chatzy.com/86265335217932 so this thread doesn't go to long :D

Comment: I managed to get the items into session storage. However the script runs even if the json is not returned from the server. **EDIT** Just seen your comment, yeah I can chat if you're okay with that